# Como realizar peticiones a una pagina web desde una app de Android

Tags: android, web

Hay una [página web](https://connect.inmarsat.com/Services/Land/IsatPhone/SMS/sms.html) que tiene un servicio web el cual manda mensajes de texto a dispositivos móviles, el servicio no es de mi propiedad, desconozco el código fuente y por lo tanto no se como se maneja internamente, en dicha página se llena un formulario y cuando le das click al boton para mandar esta manda el formulario al servidor para que se procese la información.

Yo necesito hacer pasar dicho servicio web a un app de android para mandar este tipo de peticiones a la página desde la app,

La estructura de datos es:

```
server=gsps.ashx
name="to" value="+8707712345678" 
name="reply_email" value="qq@qq.com" 
name="message" value="Hola Mundo"
```

He intentando implementar esto usando `httpHandler` pero no se como verificar que el mensaje ha sido enviado y tampoco puedo capturar la respuesta del servidor, alguien me podria decir como hacerlo

Aquí la clase httpHandler:

```
public class httpHandler {
public String post(String posturl){
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(posturl);
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("to","+870776458585"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reply_email","qq@qq.com"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message","Hola Mundo!"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        HttpResponse resp = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        HttpEntity ent = resp.getEntity();/*y obtenemos una respuesta*/
        String text = EntityUtils.toString(ent);
        return text;
    }
  catch(Exception e) { return "error";}
 }
}
```

Aqui mi MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView mDumpTextView;
private ScrollView mScrollView;
private EditText mTextoEditor1;
private Button mBotonSend;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

    mBotonSend = (Button) findViewById( R.id.bt2_SendButton );

    mBotonSend.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            httpHandler handler = new httpHandler();
            String txt = handler.post("https://gsps.ashx");

        }
    } );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo que usas un servicio web el cual manda mensajes de texto a dispositivos moviles.

Lo que entiendo que quieres hacer es pasar dicho servicio web a un app de android.

Entiendo que tienes el codigo que entrega el navegador al descargar la pagina.

Pero para realizar la app que quieres hay dos opciones viables:

1.-Si eres dueño de ese servicio y por lo tanto tienes el conocimiento del codigo fuente (no solo el html del navegador), deberias ser capaz de programar la interfaz de andriod ya que solo es diseñarla dado que la logica ya esta hospedada en tu servidor en la nube, por lo que deberias de presentar tu duda mas en especifico si este es tu caso

2.-Si el servicio no es de tu propiedad y por lo tanto no sabes como se maneja internamente aun es posible hacerlo, en dicha pagina llenas un formulario y cuando le das click al boton para mandar esta manda el formulario al servidor para que se procese la informacion, tu puedes mandar este tipo de peticiones a la pagina desde una app de android pero tienes que mandar la informacion en la misma estructura que lo hace la pagina original, si este es tu caso edita tu pregunta con la info que tienes sobre la estructura de datos que vas a enviar y pon tu duda mas clara sobre el problema con el que te tiene "parado"

Comment: `Fanatidark`, ya he editado la pregunta y definido la estructura de datos